# ListBox.SelectedItem

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a `ListBox` with items that fill `TextBox`es.  How do I identify the text string that is selected when a selection is made from the `ListBox`. Here's my XAML code for the `ListBox`:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="InputPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Input" Style="{StaticResource H2Style}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Select Scenario:" Style="{StaticResource H3Style}"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="ScenarioList" Margin="0,0,20,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionChanged="ScenarioList_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="Scenario1">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ListBoxTextStyle}" Text="1) Pick a single photo" />
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="Scenario2">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ListBoxTextStyle}" Text="2) Pick multiple files" />
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="Scenario3">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ListBoxTextStyle}" Text="3) Pick a folder" />
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="Scenario4">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ListBoxTextStyle}" Text="4) Save a file" />
            </ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

I have tried all kinds of things in my `selection_changed` method. Here's the latest one:

```
object selectedItem = ScenarioList.SelectedItem;
ListBoxItem selected = this.ScenarioList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(this.ScenarioList.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
string tempStr = selected.Content.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListBoxItem listBox_Item = listBox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
MessageBox.Show("You have selected " + listBox_Item.Content.ToString());
```

or You can try this one on Selection changed event

```
 private void ScenarioList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
  {
        if (((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem != null)
        MessageBox.Show("You have selected " + (ListBox)sender).SelectedItem);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do it like this:

```
var selectedText = ((TextBlock)((ListBoxItem)ScenarioList.SelectedItem).Content).Text
```

You can also get at it from SelectionChangedEventArgs something like:

```
public void ScenarioList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.AddedItems[0] as ListBoxItem;
    var selectedText = ((TextBlock)item.Content).Text;
}
```

Comment: Nathan, Thanks, that's the ticket.  Works like a charm.  Lotsa parens, I'll have to study it a bit to understand.  Thanks again.